Is there a way to find the parent object of a variable passed to a function?
I have a generic form filling system using C# and JavaScript. The data for a form comes from a C# class.
I am upgrading the system so it can do multi-page forms (without having to call back the C# to change pages). The class members now have attributes indicating which page each field of the form is shown on.
When the form is submitted from JavaScript to C#, it calls a C# function on the server which validates the input. If the input is invalid, it passes back an error message.
I currently use a Check function, which throws an exception if the checked assertion is not true. It would be great if the check function could tell the JavaScript which page the field with the error is on. I was hoping to be able to pass the field value into the check function, and it magically to be able to work out what class the field came from, look up the page number, and pass that back.
Example code:
public class PageAttribute : Attribute {
    public int Page;
    public PageAttribute(int page) {
        Page = page;
    }
}

public class Example {
    public int Id;
    [Page(1)]
    public string Name;
    [Page(1)]
    public string Address;
    [Page(2)]
    public int Calls;
    [Page(2)]
    public int Emails;
}

public class CheckException : ApplicationException {
    public int Page;
    public CheckException(string message, int page = 0) : base(message) {
        Page = page;
    }
}

void Check<T>(Object o, T item, Func<T, bool> validate, string message) {
    if (!validate(item)) {
        Type type = o.GetType();
        // Somehow magically find out which element in object o item comes from
        string name = "Calls";
        MemberInfo info = type.GetField(name) as MemberInfo;
        PageAttribute p = info.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(PageAttribute)) as PageAttribute;
        throw new CheckException(message, p == null ? 0 : p.Page);
    }
}

void Main() {
    Example e = new Example() { Id = 1, Name = "test", Calls = 3 };
    Check(e, e.Calls, x => x == 3, "Calls not equal to 3");
    Check(e, e.Calls, x => x == 2, "Calls not equal to 2");
}


Well, there's fundamentally no way of knowing where a particular value came from - the same value could be present in lots of places. (If you've just got the value 5, you presumably wouldn't want to find every occurrence of the number 5 in memory.)
However, there's a better approach than reflection here here: CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute. That allows the compiler to provide "the expression used to provide an argument".
Here's a really short example of that:
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

string x = "Hello";

ShowValue(x.Length);

void ShowValue(
    int value,
    [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(value))] string? expression = null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{expression} = {value}");
}


That prints x.Length = 5.
So in your code, you'd need to:

Change Check to have an optional parameter like the expression one above
Find the last . in the expression
Get the field named by the remainder
Get the PageAttribute associated with that field

Note that this is somewhat brittle - if someone refactors the call to Check to use a local variable for example, that would break the processing.
I'd personally use typeof(T) instead of o.GetType(), and I'd recommend changing all your public fields into properties by the way, but those are changes somewhat unrelated to the core question

Thanks - that would be useful if I was on NET 10, but I am stiking to long-term support versions. In my current version, it says CallerArgumentExpression is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Turns out you can hack round that - see my answer below

@NikkiLocke: "C# 10" isn't the same as ".NET 10". C# 10 shipped with .NET 6, so I'd expect it to work there... but it definitely works in .NET 8 which is the most recent LTS version. (.NET 6 drops out of support pretty soon.)

Assuming that the second parameter will always be in the form of a single member access (x.y), consider taking an expression tree, instead of the first two parameters.
You can easily get the MemberInfo of the member that is accessed from the expression tree.
void Check<T>(Expression<Func<T>> itemSelector, Func<T, bool> validate, string message) {
    var item = itemSelector.Compile()();
    
    if (!validate(item)) {
        if (itemSelector.Body is MemberExpression memberExpr) {
            var info = memberExpr.Member;
            if (info.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(PageAttribute)) is PageAttribute p) {
                throw new CheckException(message, p == null ? 0 : p.Page);
            } else {
                // what if it doesn't have a page attribute?
            }
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentException("itemSelector not in the correct format!");
        }
    }
}

Example usage:
Example e = new Example() { Id = 1, Name = "test", Calls = 3 };
Check(() => e.Calls, x => x == 3, "Calls not equal to 3");


Here is the code i ended up with, based on Jon Skeet's excellent answer:
        void check<T>(T value, Func<T, bool> validate, Func<string> error, string expression) {
            if (!validate(value)) {
                int p = Page;
                if (p < 0) {
                    p = 0;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(expression)) {
                        string member = expression.Split('.').Last();
                        if (!Pages.TryGetValue(member, out p)) {
                            // Retrieve page from type and add to dictionary
                            FieldAttribute f = null;
                            FieldInfo fld = Type.GetField(member);
                            if (fld == null) {
                                PropertyInfo prop = Type.GetProperty(member);
                                if (prop != null)
                                    f = prop.GetCustomAttribute<FieldAttribute>();
                            } else {
                                f = fld.GetCustomAttribute<FieldAttribute>();
                            }
                            if (f != null)
                                p = f.Page;
                            Pages[member] = p;
                        }
                    }
                }
                throw new FormException(error(), p);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Check a condition is true on a field. Throw a FormException with the field page number if not.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The member item to check</param>
        /// <param name="validate">A validation fnction to call, passing the value</param>
        /// <param name="error">A method to call which returns the error message</param>
        /// <param name="expression">Filled in automatically by the compiler</param>
        public void Check<T>(T value, Func<T, bool> validate, Func<string> error, [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(value))] string expression = null) {
            check(value, validate, error, expression);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check a condition is true on a field. Throw a FormException with the field page number if not.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The member item to check</param>
        /// <param name="validate">A validation fnction to call, passing the value</param>
        /// <param name="error">The error message string</param>
        /// <param name="expression">Filled in automatically by the compiler</param>
        public void Check<T>(T value, Func<T, bool> validate, string error, [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(value))] string expression = null) {
            check(value, validate, () => error, expression);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check a condition is true on a field. Throw a FormException with the field page number if not.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The member item to check</param>
        /// <param name="condition">Whether the item is valis</param>
        /// <param name="error">The error message string</param>
        /// <param name="expression">Filled in automatically by the compiler</param>
        public void Check<T>(T value, bool condition, string error, [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(value))] string expression = null) {
            check(value, v => condition, () => error, expression);
        }

I tried this in .net 6, and it complained about CallerArgumentExpression being inaccessible. However, I found that you could fix that by declaring it internal, as follows:
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices {
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    internal sealed class CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute : Attribute {
        public CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute(string parameterName) {
            ParameterName = parameterName;
        }

        public string ParameterName { get; }
    }
}

I found that tip at How can I use CallerArgumentExpression with Visual Studio 2022 and .net Standard 2.0 or .net 4.8? - thanks Matthew Watson

I've just tried my sample code with a .NET 6.0 project, and it works fine. Are you sure you were targeting .NET 6.0 rather than .NET Standard or .NET Framework?

The code is in a library written for net core, and then used by a net 6 application. Sorry I didn't make that clear. With the addition of the internal class, it works fine. Thanks for your help.
